# Setting Dropdownlist to a value from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My drop down has the following values:

```
US USA
IN India
```

And other countries.

In my jQuery I want to set the selected item in dropdown to "IN India" by just passing "India". I would like to know if there is a way to achieve that.

Comment: @Amit please show some code snap how you bind drop down initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like?

HTML

```
​<select id="select1">
<option val="US USA">USA</option>
<option val="IN India">India</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select1').find('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().indexOf('India')!=-1) {
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
});
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/FKdpn/

Obviously this is tied to the document.ready function, but you can change it as per your requirements. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Pulkit.. i was looking for something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. One way is to use two arrays, one for country abbreviations and second for country names. Use the second array to find index for the selected value. Then, use the index for the first array. Then concatenate the result(IN) with the selected value "India".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to inform that i already have my grid populated. I just wanted to know if there is some contains function to set the value of my dropdown.

Comment: Of course there is. Use `bind` function to listen to selection of dropdown value and use a custom function to show your customized value. Refer to jquery documentation for more information on `bind` function.